# Kivy Screen Manager, find screen instance names?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Currently working on a kivy based program but need to pass a variable between 2 screens, I'm using the screen manager and need to find the instance of the 'LoginScreen' to get the user's name to then be displayed on the 'HomeScreen'

Does screenmanager create an instance of the user defined screen and if so how do I access this instance

If not how do I find the instance created of the 'Login Screen'

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import *
from kivy.config import Config

import hashlib

import sqlite3

with sqlite3.connect('scorestore.db') as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()

kivy.require("1.11.0")

Builder.load_string("""
<RegisterScreen>
    name: 'register'
    FloatLayout:
        Image:
            source: 'scorestorelogo.png'
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.8
            pos_hint: {"x":0.1 , "y":0.535}

        Label:
            text: "Name"
            pos_hint: {"x":-0.3, "y":0.275}

        TextInput:
            id: name
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.05
            pos_hint: {"x":0.3, "y":0.75}

        Label:
            text: "Email Address"
            pos_hint: {"x":-0.3, "y":0.1925}

        TextInput:
            id: email
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.05
            pos_hint: {"x":0.3, "y":0.667}

        Label:
            text: "Password"
            pos_hint: {"x":-0.3, "y":0.11}

        TextInput:
            id: password
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.05
            pos_hint: {"x":0.3, "y":0.584}
            password: True

        Label:
            text: "Club ID"
            pos_hint: {"x":-0.3, "y":0.0275}

        TextInput:
            id: clubid
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.05
            pos_hint: {"x":0.3, "y":0.501}

        Button:
            font_size: 30
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x":0.3, "y":0.35}
            text: "Register Account"
            on_press: 
                root.register_account(name.text, email.text, password.text, clubid.text)

        Button:
            font_size: 20
            size_hint: 0.15, 0.05
            pos_hint: {"x":0.82, "y":0.500}
            text: "Find Club ID"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'find-club'

        Label:
            id: error
            text: ""
            pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": -0.2}

        Button:
            font_size: 20
            text: "Return to login"
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.05
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.4, "y":0.15}
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'login'

<LoginScreen>
    name: 'login'
    FloatLayout:
        Image:
            source: 'scorestorelogo.png'
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.8
            pos_hint: {"x":0.1 , "y":0.535}

        Label:
            text: "User Email Address"
            pos_hint: {"x":-0.3, "y":0.1925}

        TextInput:
            id: email
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.05
            pos_hint: {"x":0.3, "y":0.667}

        Label:
            text: "Password"
            pos_hint: {"x":-0.3, "y":0.11}

        TextInput:
            id: password
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.05
            pos_hint: {"x":0.3, "y":0.584}
            password: True

        Button:
            font_size: 30
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x":0.3, "y":0.42}
            text: "Log in"
            on_press:
                root.login(email.text, password.text)

        Label:
            font_size: 20
            text: "or"
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "y":-0.12}

        Button:
            font_size: 30
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x":0.3, "y":0.23}
            text: "Register"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'register'

        Label:
            id: error
            text: ""
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "y":-0.4}



<FindClubScreen>
    name: 'find-club'
    Image:
        source: 'scorestorelogo.png'
        size_hint: 0.8, 0.8
        pos_hint: {"x":0.1 , "y":0.535}

    Label:
        text: "Search club name"
        pos_hint: {"x":-0.25, "y":0.275}

    TextInput:
        id: club
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
        pos_hint: {"x":0.35, "y":0.7}

    Label:
        id: no_clubs
        text: ''
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.05, "y": 0}

    Label:
        id: index
        text: ""
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.05, "y": 0.07}

    Label:
        id: result_list
        text: ""
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.08, "y": -0.05}


    Button:
        font_size: 30
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.075
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.4, "y": 0.6}  
        text: "Search Clubs"
        on_press: 
            root.get_club(club.text)

    Label:
        text: "Can't see your club? Try changing your search terms"  
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.05, "y": -0.4}    

    Button:
        font_size: 30
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.075
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.4, "y": 0.15}
        text: "Register Account"
        on_press:
            root.manager.current = 'register'

<HomeScreen>
    name: 'home'
    Image:
        source: 'scorestorelogo.png'
        size_hint: 0.8, 0.8
        pos_hint: {"x":0.1 , "y":0.535}

    Label:
        id: user
        text: ""
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": 0}


""")


class LoginScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        self.email = ""
        self.password = ""
        self.password_attempt = ""
        self.user_name = ""

    def get_password(self):
        cursor.execute('''SELECT password FROM Users WHERE email LIKE ?''', (self.email,))
        user_pw = cursor.fetchall()
        user_pw = str(user_pw)
        user_pw = user_pw.strip("[]")
        user_pw = user_pw.strip("()")
        user_pw = user_pw.strip(",")
        user_pw = user_pw.strip("'")
        return user_pw

    def get_user_name(self):
        cursor.execute('''SELECT name FROM Users WHERE email LIKE ?''', (self.email,))
        user_name = cursor.fetchall()
        user_name = str(user_name)
        user_name = user_name.strip("[]")
        user_name = user_name.strip("()")
        user_name = user_name.strip(",")
        user_name = user_name.strip("'")
        return user_name

    def login(self, emailText, passwordText):
        self.ids.error.text = ""
        self.email = emailText
        self.password_attempt = passwordText
        self.password = self.get_password()
        self.user_name = self.get_user_name()
        self.password_attempt = hashlib.md5(self.password_attempt.encode())
        self.password_attempt = self.password_attempt.hexdigest()

        if self.password == self.password_attempt:
            print("Login successful")
            sm.current = 'home'

        else:
            self.ids.error.text = "Login unsuccessful please check your details and try again"
            return


class RegisterScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        self.fullname = ""
        self.email = ""
        self.password = ""
        self.clubID = 0
        self.userID = 0
        self.last_user = []
        self.last_uid = 0

    def create_uid(self, last_user):
        for i in last_user:
            last_uid = i
            break

        last_uid = str(last_uid)
        last_uid = last_uid.strip("()")
        last_uid = last_uid.strip(",")
        last_uid = int(last_uid)
        userID = last_uid + 1
        return userID

    def register_account(self, nameText, emailText, passwordText, clubidText):
        self.ids.error.text = ""
        try:
            self.fullname = nameText
            self.email = emailText.lower()
            self.password = passwordText
            self.clubID = int(clubidText)
            self.userID = self.create_uid(cursor.execute('''SELECT max(userID) as userID FROM Users;'''))

        except ValueError:
            self.ids.error.text = "Invalid input check format of inputted info"
            return

        already = cursor.execute('''SELECT email FROM Users WHERE email LIKE ?''', (self.email,))
        for i in already:
            already = i
            break

        if len(already[0]) > 0:
            self.ids.error.text = "An account with that email already exists"
            return

        self.password = hashlib.md5(self.password.encode())
        self.password = self.password.hexdigest()

        cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO Users(userID, name, clubID, email, password) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)''',
                       (self.userID, self.fullname, self.clubID, self.email, self.password))
        db.commit()

        sm.current = 'login'


class FindClubScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        self.club = ""
        self.results = []
        self.search_terms = []
        self.result_labels = []

    def get_club(self, clubText):
        self.club = clubText
        self.club = self.club.split()
        self.search_terms = []
        self.results = []
        self.result_labels = []
        for i in self.club:
            if i.lower() not in ["college", "rifle", "club", "school", "association", "and"]:
                self.search_terms.append(i)
            else:
                self.club.remove(i)

        for i in self.search_terms:
            self.results += cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM Clubs WHERE name LIKE ?''', ('%'+i+'%',))

        self.ids.no_clubs.text = ""
        self.ids.index.text = ""
        self.ids.result_list.text = ""

        if len(self.results) == 0:
            self.ids.no_clubs.text = "No clubs with that name found"
            return

        self.ids.index.text = "ID, Club name"

        count = 0
        for i in range(len(self.results)):
            count += 1
            self.ids.result_list.text += str(self.results[i]).strip('()') + "\n"
            if count == 5:
                break


class HomeScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        self.ids.user.text = LoginScreenInstance.user_name


sm = ScreenManager(transition=FadeTransition())

sm.add_widget(LoginScreen(name='login'))
sm.add_widget(RegisterScreen(name='register'))
sm.add_widget(FindClubScreen(name='find-club'))
sm.add_widget(HomeScreen(name='home'))


class ScoreStore(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ScoreStore().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing the class definition with an instance of the class. There is no such thing as `LoginScreen.user_name` because there's no code to add this attribute to the class (nor should there be). But if you make an instance of the class, e.g. `l = LoginScreen()`, then `l.user_name` has the value you assigned when the class was initialised.

Instead you need to access the `user_name` attribute of the `LoginScreen` instance that you care about. If you don't know how to do that, please post a minimal runnable example with a simple case where you can't make the connection.

Comment: I believe the kivy screenmanager creates an instance of LoginScreen I just can't find it to reference it

Comment: @drift http://inclem.net/2019/06/20/kivy/widget_interactions_between_python_and_kv/

Answer (score 0):

Your `LoginScreen` define `user_name` as instance level attribute. This means, in order to access instance level attribute, you must create instance of your class which is `LoginScreen` in your case. To address your current issue, you can change your following line of code from

```
self.ids.user.text = LoginScreen.user_name
```

to

```
login_screen= LoginScreen()
self.ids.user.text = login_screen.user_name
```

You can read further about instance and class level attribute at [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/class-instance-attributes-python/).

Comment: This doesnt actually work because I need to access the instance of the class which is created by the screen manager

Comment: In any case, simple rule applies here. When you define self.user_name, you are telling it to be instance specific where as attribute at class level scope define class level. You may refer the link attached which will help you to clarify further. Hope this  help.

Comment: How could I make the HomeScreen user attribute always be the same as the one in the LoginScreen class?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get what you are asking.

Comment: The home screen is the screen displayed after you log in, the login screen gets the users name, could the users name be easily passed to the home screen?

Comment: Yes you can. You need to modify the __init__() of HomeScreen to accept an extra variable which is Login instance. You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501706/python-how-do-i-pass-variables-between-class-instances-or-get-the-caller  which demonstrate the idea.